# Evaluate code block in a function parameter in lua

Tags: lambda, lua, anonymous-function

I wasn't really sure how to title the question, but consider the following lua code:

```
print(function ()
    s = ""
    for i = 1, 10 do
      s = s..tostring(i)
    end
    return s
  end)
```

But this prints only the function address, since function() returns a closure. Is there a way to evaluate the anonymous function? Like in scheme where I can embrace the lambda in additional brackets?

```
((lambda ()(display "Hello World")))
```

Of course I know, I could define the function beforehand and call it later, but I was just curious if this is possible in lua. Thanks in advance for all replys.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to wrap the function definition in parentheses and then call it by adding `()` after. Putting this in the Lua interpreter:

```
> print((function ()
    s=""
    for i=1,10 do
       s=s..tostring(i)
    end
    return s
  end)())
```

gives the following output

```
> 12345678910
```

Comment: thanks, i had a similar idea but i haven't wrapped the function in brackets. looks a little bit more ugly than scheme, but at least it works :D

Answer (score 4):

If this is a global behaviour you want, the simplest solution would be to hook print so that it evaluates any functions passed to it. That way you can simply leave the call sites as lambdas.

Comment: interessting possiblity, i was just learning lua, and didn't know you could do that. i'll keep it in mind